# What does the executable `[` do?

Tags: linux, bash

#### My question:

- There is an executable file on my machine named `[`. What does it do?

#### More information:

One of the questions on a homework assignment due last week was "What executable programs have names that are just one character long, and what do they do?"

I ran the command: `find $PATH{1,2,3,4,5,6,7} -executable -name "?"` (I saved each part of my PATH into variables named PATH1, PATH2, PATH3, etc.)

Part of the output was:

```
/usr/bin/X
/usr/bin/w
/usr/bin/[
```

I've used `w` before, I know what it does. I didn't know what `X` did, and there was no man page, so I ran the command. And in the output it told me to go to "http://wiki.x.org" and all was good.

But there's no man page for `[`, and I can't even figure out how to run the `[` command!

```
$ /usr/bin/[
/usr/bin/[: missing ']'

$ source /usr/bin/[
-bash: source: /usr/bin/[: cannot execute binary file
```

I've turned in the homework with a big "???" next to my entry for `[`, but I still want to know what it does. Or if it's even an actual executable at all.

Comment: I suggest `man [`.

Comment: Try `[ 3 -eq 3 ] && echo "three equals three"` and `[ 3 -eq 4 ] && echo "three equals four"`.

Comment: Thanks to sepp2k, I understand what '[' is now. It's syntactic sugar for `test expression`. Only, your last argument HAS to be a `]`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww I'm pretty sure shell-scripting counts as programming by most definitions of the word.

Comment: @sepp2k - Yes, I agree. Where's the shell scripting part in this question? The best I can tell, it is just a question on how commands work (or how a particular command works). And its been asked so many times before you'd have to put in some effort to not find an answer.

Comment: Also see [What is the purpose of square bracket executable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257014/56041), [How are '/usr/bin/[' and '/usr/bin/test' related?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/362205/56041), [`test` and `[` - different binaries, any difference?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28682/56041) and friends on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you got was actually from `[`, not the shell. That is you did actually run `[` and `[` complained that it wanted a `]` in its list of arguments.

So the simplest way to run `[` would be `[ ]`, which does nothing and returns false.

What `[` does is to evaluate a condition. It's often used in if-statements like this:

```
if [ some-condition ]
then
  do_something
fi
```

This looks as if the brackets are part of the syntax of `if`, but they're not. It's just a call to the program `[` with the arguments `some-condition` and `]`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried running `$ []` and got `-bash: []: command not found`. But now that you've told me to run `$ [ ]` after explaining what/why this was, I get the output I expect and everything makes sense.

Comment: Furthermore, it explains what I used to think was a weird bash stylistic decision to force users to separate the brackets from arguments in their if statements with spaces. Now I see that it's a function in and of itself

Comment: Notice that, at least in Bash, `[` uses the Bash built-in, not `/usr/bin/[`.

Answer (score 2):

`[` is basically syntactic sugar, an emergency backup version of `test` that looks better in an if statement. In bash you can (and probably should) virtually always use `[[ ]]` instead, which is parsed directly by the interpreter and won't spawn a new process. You should also read the bash man page thoroughly and understand `(( ))` which does mathematical evaluation.

Comment: `test` is a shell builtin command and hence it doesn't spawn a process.

Comment: Is now - thanks for pointing that out. Wasn't always. I still prefer the double-brackets, but that's likely more a matter of habit than actual reason now.

Answer (score 0):

`[` is a synonym for `test`

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html

> test - check file types and compare values

https://linux.die.net/man/1/test

The error you are getting `missing ]` is because this synonym for test is executed as

`[ test_expression ]` and so was incomplete without the closing bracket `]`

Comment: Not my downvote, but *please* avoid linking the ABS. It's the W3Schools of bash -- full of outdated or misleading information and bad-practice examples, yet having an inordinately high PageRank.

Comment: Better sources on this topic would include [the POSIX spec for `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031), and [the official bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the ABS, I think other errors you've corrected me on in the past could probably be traced back there.

Comment: I wonder why I got downvoted though :/ Whenever I downvote somebody I leave a comment on why i did